# Using Flask with Elixir and SQL alchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask, python-elixir

I am trying to use Elixir with Flask. Reason being using SQL Alchemy directly has me confused about the data insert on Many to Many relations. So I have created the models file and generated the tables I need.

For SQl alchemy I call from flask like this:

```
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
```

How to do same for Elixir? I have a model method for get_or_init on Entity so I am trying to use that as well.

When I try to use SQLAlchemy itself (since elixir is just wrapper) I get:

```
AttributeError: type object 'User' has no attribute 'query' where User is a model.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I haven't used Elixir myself, the issue with missing `query` is simple - you need to add the [query property](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session.html?highlight=query_property#sqlalchemy.orm.scoping.ScopedSession.query_property) to the models yourself:

```
class User(object):
    query = Session.query_property()
```

Comment: that kind of sucks because there is a whole bunch of other properties. I ditched elixir because it seems only way is to write a wrapper or something. If you can help with my other query I won't need to solve this. I accept it as a right answer ofcourse since it will kind of solve the problem. thanks.

Comment: when using `declarative` syntax, this property is usually set to `declarative_base(...)` returned class, which is the base class for all the models, and as such all models will have the `query` property. And if you do not use `declarative`, still nothing prevents you from setting this property to some common base class.